# How to avoid converting date to idate in R data.table fwrite 1.9.7?

Tags: r, data.table

Having installed data.table 1.9.7 in a windows machine, I have a *data.table* A where one of its columns is of *Date* type. I want to export A to a *CSV* file with *fwrite* but when I run

```
fwrite(A,file="out1.csv")
```

the *Date* column is transformed to *IDate* integer type. I need to keep the *date* format because this file will be used to a different application, not R. How can I not have the Date column transformed to *IDate*? My first attempt was to use

```
A[,theDate:=as.character(theDate)]
```

but it takes about 1000 seconds in a 100M rows data.table. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Since you have 100M rows, I suppose you have some repeating dates, so it might be faster to do something like `A[, theDate := as.character(theDate[1L]), by=theDate]`. `fwrite` is fairly new, so I'm guessing this treatment of dates is an oversight and they'd welcome a feature request on improving it.

Comment: @Frank  Nice idea.  Dates are on the long to do list: [#1664](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1664).  Your idea triggered a thought ... fwrite could do a lookup internally rather than converting each and every date separately.

Answer (score 4):

This is now implemented and is fast. Please update to `data.table` v1.9.8+.
You can control how dates are written with `dateTimeAs="ISO"|"squash"|"epoch"|"write.csv"`. See the current version of `fwrite`'s manual page [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4/topics/fwrite).

Comment: The argument `dateAs` no longer exists. Will have to go back to `write.csv` since my output requirements are not one of the three options in the new `dateTimeAs` argument.

Comment: @ddunn801 What is your requirement please? Thank you. The [manual page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4/topics/fwrite) does include the sentence "We may be able to support one or two more specific options if required."

Comment: A straightforward date only option would be useful: something like 2017-02-16 or similar. After playing around a bit, I can first convert the date to a character field and then convert it back after the speedy `fwrite`. TLDR:  save the extra two options for something trickier. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @ddunn801 It already does that:  2017-02-16 is ISO format.  What exactly is going wrong when you try ISO? You shouldn't have to convert and convert back at all.